# Почему не заносит данные?

Tags: php

Я делаю такую штуку со стороны сервера:

```
if($_GET['startpoke'] == '')
 if ($_POST['startpoke'] == '')
   exit('Пусто');
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `startpoke` (img,name_poke,life,atk,def,exp,type) SELECT img,name,life,atk,def,exp,type FROM pokemon WHERE id_pok = ".$_GET['startpoke'])
```

А в шаблоне такую штуку:

```
<TD><input name='startpoke' type='radio' value='1' class='checkbox' ><b>001 Bulbasaur</b><br><img src=img/001.jpg width=250 height=190 border=1></TD>
<TD><input name='startpoke' type='radio' value='4' class='checkbox'  ><b>004 Charmander</b> <br><img src=img/004.jpg width=250 height=190 border=1></TD>
```

Ошибку не выбивает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать.

Comment: А вы уверены, что в `$_GET['startpoke']` что-то есть? Если вы посылаете данные `$_POST`'ом, то происходит логический облом. И вообще, у меня дежавю или этот вопрос уже звучал?

Comment: Он не так звучал =)

Comment: И там не пусто! Вот это проверяет на пустоту `if($_GET['startpoke'] == '')`

    if ($_POST['startpoke'] == '')
      exit('Пусто');

Comment: В phpMyAdmin вбейте sql запрос, и покажите результат...

Comment: >1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql_query("INSERT INTO `startpoke` (img,name_poke,life,atk,def,exp,type) SELEC' at line 1 

Вот ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте такой sql в  phpmyadmin

```
INSERT INTO `startpoke` (`img`,`name_poke`,`life`,`atk`,`def`,`exp`,`type`)
SELECT `img`, `name`, `life`, `atk`, `def`, `exp`, `type` FROM `pokemon` WHERE `id_pok` = XXX
```

Вместо XXX - id существующего покемона

Конечный результат

```
<?php
    if ( !preg_match('/^\d+$/',$_POST['startpoke']) ) die('error');
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `startpoke` (`img`,`name_poke`,`life`,`atk`,`def`,`exp`,`type`) SELECT `img`, `name`, `life`, `atk`, `def`, `exp`, `type` FROM `pokemon` WHERE `id_pok` ='.$_POST['startpoke'].';';
    mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

Comment: Так оно заносит

Comment: Тогда пишите в php:

mysql_query('INSERT INTO `startpoke` (`img`,`name_poke`,`life`,`atk`,`def`,`exp`,`type`)
SELECT `img`, `name`, `life`, `atk`, `def`, `exp`, `type` FROM `pokemon` WHERE `id_pok` ='.$_GET['startpoke']);

Comment: >1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql_query('INSERT INTO `startpoke` (`img`,`name_poke`,`life`,`atk`,`def`,`exp`' at line 1

Comment: @Prikol, сделайте php таким:

if($_GET['startpoke'] == '')
 if ($_POST['startpoke'] == '')
   exit('Пусто');
$sql = 'INSERT INTO \`startpoke\` (\`img\`,\`name_poke\`,\`life\`,\`atk\`,\`def\`,\`exp\`,\`type\`) SELECT \`img\`, \`name\`, \`life\`, \`atk\`, \`def\`, \`exp\`, \`type\` FROM \`pokemon\` WHERE \`id_pok\` ='.$_GET['startpoke'].';';
echo $sql;
echo "\n";
mysql_query($sql);

и сюда результат

Comment: Я сделал много правок кода) Поэтому заново нужно скопировать)

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_GET['startpoke'] == '')
 if ($_POST['startpoke'] == '')
   exit('Пусто');
```

Во-первых, это совершенно некорректно, используйте `empty()` хотя бы, да и то, в вашей логике до метода `POST` даже не доходит дело.
Зачем Вам обратные кавычки у названия таблицы `startpoke`?
И интерполируйте переменную в строку напрямую, не надо точки, просто впишите ее в запрос в нужном месте.
Насчет двух запросов сразу не уверен, но разве не нужно их `;` друг от друга отделить???

Comment: Если так присмотреться , то можно увидеть что я копирую информацию с одной таблицы в другую =)

Comment: вот сервер и ругается кстати, что он не понимает ваших двух запросов сразу. Он понимает только VALUES после перечисления столбцов таблицы в скобках.

Comment: Если так, тогда логичней VALUES(а здесь ваш SELECT запрос)

Comment: Всё он понимает. Я так-же первый раз увидел такую конструкцию! Но чуть любознательности,  руки и phpmyadmin -  и сам убедился что это работает!

Comment: Да, Вы правы, проверил в консоли, без VALUES тоже работает.=)

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO `startpoke` (`img`,`name_poke`,`life`,`atk`,`def`,`exp`,`type`) SELECT `img`, `name`, `life`, `atk`, `def`, `exp`, `type` FROM `pokemon` WHERE `id_pok` =;  оно мне сразу такую штуку выбивает

Comment: Я немного подправил код и вод ошибка Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\style\register.php on line 51

Comment: ошибка здесь : $sql = "INSERT INTO `startpoke` (`img`,`name_poke`,`life`,`atk`,`def`,`exp`,`type`) SELECT `img`, `name`, `life`, `atk`, `def`, `exp`, `type` FROM `pokemon` WHERE `id_pok` ='.$_GET['startpoke'].";

Comment: Перед последней двойной кавычкей одинарную вставь.

Comment: выдает error

Comment: Точно... У тебя форма передаёт в $_POST, замени ( таких места - два ) $_GET на $_POST и будет работать

Comment: Черт побери, ты крут =)